# IConfiguration in WebJobs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs

I have an ASP.NET Core WebJobs project that is using class libraries from an ASP.NET Core web app.

In the web app, I'm simply using `IConfiguration` to access all my settings. In my WebJobs app, I have the following lines which appear to use `IConfigurationRoot`.

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();
```

So, how do I go from `IConfigurationRoot` to `IConfiguration`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IConfigurationRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationroot?view=aspnetcore-2.1) is derived from `IConfiguration`

```
public interface IConfigurationRoot : Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration
```

So you can assign it to an `IConfiguration` variable

```
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();
```

Comment: I have a follow up question -- maybe a separate question is a better idea. How do I make my configuration available to my class libraries in my WebJobs? The class library that comes from my web app is expecting `IConfiguration config` in its constructor. In my ASP.NET Core app, this is all handled in `Startup.cs` so I have easy access to my configuration throughout my app -- including the class libraries. Currently the shared class library is not able to resolve my configuration in my WebJobs app.

Comment: @Sam you could consider registering the interface with the service collection so it is available for injection. But ideally from a design perspective it is usually not advised to be injecting that interface all around. So you may need to review your design choices.